# Does electrum use static fees?

Tags: wallet, transaction-fees, electrum

I use electrum as a bit wallet and curious to find out if it's uses static or dynamic fees as I never set the option, and the fees seem to be 0.00001 B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent versions of Electrum use dynamic fees. It has been like this for several versions, although for some versions you needed to enable it in your preferences. Check your preferences and see if there is a dynamic fees option. You can also just upgrade to using the latest version of Electrum.